# Android - PHP services to show message to users

Tags: php, android, service, refresh

I am using php services to show message to user. It works fine but on every refresh it show 3 dialog boxes messages where I am only refreshing once.

How to prevent that, Is that php bug or android? Any idea will do thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem then the problem in your android code. 
Can you post the code and service response sample if possible so that it would be easier to understand the problem.